# Problem displaying NiceSelect plugin in Table

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, combobox

According to the following two images, whenever I try to use this plugin in Table, it does not display `Combobox` values on the table.

**Nice Select plugin** Address Url:
https://jqueryniceselect.hernansartorio.com/

[image]

[image]

**What I want is for the values inside the `Combobox` to be displayed on the table.**

As shown below:

[image]

Comment: what is a combobox? Is it the same as a select dropdown?

Comment: @ElisabethMedlien yes

Comment: Right now your options are nested inside the table. You have to make your list behave like a modal. When you click the combobox it should display a modal containing your options, and the modals position can be calculated from the click event

Comment: @ElisabethMedlien In fact, the **css code** of this plugin should be changed, so I asked if anyone had such a problem to say this, and I also posted the address of this plugin.

Comment: I downloaded the plugin and everything works fine. Without your code it is very hard to know what breaks it

Comment: @Elissi Did you use the plugin in the table?